# Superset - Multi-language option for chart and data label

Tags: translation, apache-superset

In superset, How I can have an internationalization support to charts and dashboards?
How the chart title and text can be displayed in the langage selected by users. And if the data can be displayed with the right langage (indeed, the label translation could be in a table, but create a selection or filter with the langage detected)

I add en et fr in langage config
Superset front end is translate but I need translate my dashboard and my charts

Thanks a lot for your idea or Help
Carole